# IF CONDITIONING IN EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a cell with some time. if the time is between 16:30 to 17:00 then the value of the next cell should be 16:45 and if value is between 6:45 to 7:15 then it should be 7:00. This has to be achieved through formula. please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula
=IF(AND(OR(HOUR(G5)=17,HOUR(G5)=16),MINUTE(G5)<30,MINUTE(G5)>15),"16:45:00",IF(AND(OR(HOUR(G5)=18,HOUR(G5)=19),MINUTE(G5)<30,MINUTE(G5)>15),"19:00:00",""))

Answer (score 0):

IF your time data is in `Column A`, enter the formula in `Column B` and format as time if required,

```
=IF(AND(A1>TIME(16,30,0),A1<TIME(17,0,0)),TIME(16,45,0),IF(AND(A1>TIME(6,45,0),A1<TIME(7,15,0)),TIME(7,0,0),A1))
```

[image]

If the time does not fall in any of the above 2 conditions, then the time will be printed as it is.